# Sql/c# Error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to off

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, file-upload

I have a web application which is giving me the following exception:

> InnerException    {"Cannot insert
>   explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'Cover' when IDENTITY_INSERT is
>   set to OFF."} System.Exception
>   {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

I'm trying to insert into a database which looks like the following:

```
dbo.File
FileID            int  PK
Title             nvarchar(50)
ISBN              nvarchar(50)
UploadDate        datetime
UserName          nvarchar(50)

dbo.Cover
CoverID           int PK
CoverFileContent  varbinary(max)
CoverMimeType     nvarchar(50)
CoverFileName     nvarchar(50)
FileID            int FK

dbo.Cover
CoverID           int  PK
CoverFileContent  varbinary(max)
CoverMimeType     nvarchar(50)
CoverFileName     nvarchar(50)
FileID            int FK
```

In this database the File table has a one to many relationship with both the Cover, and the Pdf table. In my application, the user first enters a description of the file, and this updates the file table, then they upload a picture associated with the file which updates the Cover table, and then they upload a PDF file (I have not got this far yet).

Right now, my MVC c# code looks like the following:

**FileController**

```
 //
    //GET: /File/CreateFile
    public ActionResult CreateFile()
    {
        File file = new File();

        return View(file);
    }

//
//POST: /File/CreateFile
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateFile(FormCollection formvalues)
{
    File file = new File();

    if (TryUpdateModel(file))
    {
        filerepository.AddFileData(file);
        filerepository.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("CreateCover", "Cover", new { id = file.FileID });
    }

    return View(file);
}
```

**Cover Controller**

```
//
        //GET: /File/CreateCover
        public ActionResult CreateCover(int id)
        {
            Cover cover = new Cover();
            cover.FileID = id;
            return View(cover);
        }

        //
        //POST: /File/CreateCover
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateCover(Cover cover)
        {
            cover.CoverMimeType = Request.Files["CoverUpload"].ContentType;
            Stream fileStream = Request.Files["CoverUpload"].InputStream;
            cover.CoverFileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files["CoverUpload"].FileName);
            int fileLength = Request.Files["CoverUpload"].ContentLength;
            cover.CoverFileContent = new byte[fileLength];
            fileStream.Read(cover.CoverFileContent, 0, fileLength);
            cover.FileID = int.Parse(Request.Form["FileID"]);
            filerepository.AddCoverData(cover);

            filerepository.Save();

            return View(cover);
            //return View("CreatePdf", "Pdf", new { id = cover.FileID });
        }
```

CreateCover View

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SampleApp.Models.Cover>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    CreateCover
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" 

runat="server">

        <h2>CreateCover</h2>

        <% using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCover", "Cover", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           { %>
           <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FileID) %>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Please Select your eBook Cover" /><br />
        <input type="file" name="CoverUpload" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />

        <% } %>

        <div>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
        </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

I was able to upload a cover once, however ever since then I've been getting this error. I noticed that in my table I had forgotten to set the PK column as IDENTITY (1, 1), however I changed this and am still getting the error.

I also don't know if it's worth mentioning, but in my database for the one image I was able to upload, the binary content in the database is pretty much "0x00000...."...This seems wrong? :)

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have also tried performing the following on the database table: SET "IDENTITY_INSERT [SampleAppDB].[dbo].[Cover] ON;" however this makes no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this issue for anyone else who is having the same problem. Simply refreshed the model in Visual Studio and it seems to have done the trick.